# Deleting row from file table using LINQ in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, filestream, filetable

I have an SQL Server with FILESTREAM enabled and a file table populated with a number of rows.
I want to be able to delete a selected row from this table using LINQ in .NET Core 3.1.

In my infrastructure layer, I have implemented the following:

```cs
public async Task<bool> DeleteReport(Guid streamId)
{
    var query = _dbContext.ReportFileTable
                          .Remove(await _dbContext.ReportFileTable
                                                  .Where(e => e.stream_id.Equals(streamId))
                                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync());
    var saved = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return saved == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

This approach works just fine for my other regular database tables, but it fails for the FileTable and returns with a timeout when executing `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` despite that the query itself shows that the row is marked for deletion.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.
```

I know that .NET Core support for FileStream is little to none. How do I get around this?

Comment: looks like the loading `.FirstOrDefaultAsync` takes too long (due to the loaded data size). Why don't you try deleting it via Id/Key only? it's so ridiculous that to delete something, we must load the whole data first. The key/id to target what we want to delete is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @King King. However, the files are roughly 1 MB in size, so I don't think it's the payload causing it. I have no trouble displaying the files' metadata and downloading the filestream. After some reading, I believe it's a question of database access rights to the FILESTREAM tables. These tables are shared with the host file system (depending on config), and I believe deleting from these tables must be done via predefined database tasks stored in the SQL server and called upon remotely.